# Logrotate does not auto rotate when based on log size

Tags: logrotate

I have a custom application (myApp) which is writing logs to the file '/var/log/myApp'. I can see the logs being written and it works fine. Now I am trying to setup logrotate for this file and for this I have created a config file '/etc/logrotate.d/myApp', the contents of which are -

```
/var/log/myApp {
   missingok
   size +10k
   start 0
   nocompress
   create 0600 root root
   rotate 10
   postrotate
     /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
   endscript
}
```

Now if i do a `logrotate -dv /etc/logrotate.d/myApp` I don't see any errors as such and when `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/myApp` is executed i.e., a forceful logrotate the log is rotated. But when the log file size exceeds 10k the log is not automatically rotated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`logrotate` rotates the logs specified in `/etc/logrotate.d/` according to the time interval configured in `/etc/logrotate.conf`.  On some distros, the default value is a week. You can override that time interval in your specific config using e.g. 'daily' in your config file.

Log files will not be rotated until `logrotate` has known about the files for at least as long as the time specified. I assume that you waited this long and/or modified the conf file?

Comment: > Log files will not be rotated until logrotate has known about the files for at least as long as the time specified.

Gwha? That's news to me. I didn't see anything in the logrotate man page about that. How would one debug a logrotate conf file without having to wait 24 hours to see if it worked?

Comment: @Logan - You use the `-f` (force) option.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/logrotate-log-does-not-need-rotating-why/15547#15547 (/var/lib/logrotate/status and -f flag)

Answer (score 2):

logrotate is working only once a day , So it's not checking your file size all the time.

if you want an effective way to keep the size lower , you should use a cron job like

for example , force the rotate every hour in your crontab

```
0 * * * * logrotate <my conf here>
```

and your logs will be , if needed, rotated every hour. I had such problem in my free-tier aws server , as the size exceed rapidly and i didn't have enough disk space to wait 24 hours for a rotate